# Удалить часть значения словаря

Tags: python, dict

Всем привет, у меня есть словарь

```
directories = {
    '1': ['2', '11'],
    '2': ['3'],
    '3': []
}
```

И я хотела бы удалять из него те значения, которые вводит пользователь.

Пользовательский ввод: 2

Результат:

```
directories = {
    '1': ['11'],
    '2': ['3'],
    '3': []
}
```

Если я правильно понимаю функционал словарей, то я должна перезаписать ключи, но не понимаю как это реализовать. Спасибо

Comment: Что именно нужно удалять из словаря? Элементы списков в значениях? Приведите пример, что вводит пользователь, и что должно получиться в итоге.

Comment: Это то что у пользователя запрашивается. А что конкретно он вводит, и что должно произойти в итоге? Если он введет 3, то удалится ключ '3' вместе с пустым списком, или удалится значение '3', из списка, соответствующего ключу '2'?

Comment: @insolor Я добавила

Comment: @insolor Вы пишете быстрее, чем я успела исправить)

Answer (score 1):

Просто идете циклом по значениям в словаре (`directories.values()`), если в значении (списке) есть введенный элемент, то удаляем его из списка:

```
directories = {
    '1': ['2', '11'],
    '2': ['3'],
    '3': []
}

doc_input = input('Введите номер документа: ')

for value in directories.values():
    if doc_input in value:
        value.remove(doc_input)
        break
else:
    # Дошли до конца цикла, и не было выхода через break
    print("Документ не найден")  

print(directories)
```

Тут происходит линейный поиск значений (последовательный перебор значений словаря, потом перебор элементов в списке), оптимальнее было бы хранить словарь, где ключи — это документы, а значения — директории, тогда поиск и удаление будет происходить за ~ константное время (т.к. поиск в хеш-таблице).

Comment: Спасибо! У меня еще одна проблема возникла параллельно с пониманием работы вложенных циклов:documents = [
    {'type': 'passport', 'number': '2207 876234', 'name': 'Василий Гупкин'},
    {'type': 'invoice', 'number': '11-2', 'name': 'Геннадий Покемонов'},
    {'type': 'insurance', 'number': '10006', 'name': 'Аристарх Павлов'}
]

directories = {
    '1': ['2207 876234', '11-2'],
    '2': ['10006'],
    '3': []
}

Comment: А вопрос в чем?)